# How to get details for a customer that is both a seller and a buyer

Tags: sql

I have a database which contains customers that are both buyers and sellers.
the customers can buy and sell houses.

I need to get details for the customers separately and still have a connection between them so i could know which customer sold to which customer.

In case a customer buys a house from a different customer how can i get the details for each customer separately?

The table I made so far for the customers is :

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  SellerID int,
  BuyerID int,
  HouseID int,
  SaleID int,
  FirstName varchar (50),
  LastName varchar (50),
  Adress varchar (50),
  BirthDate Date,
  City varchar (50),
  HomePhone varchar (50),
  PRIMARY KEY (SellerID, BuyerID),
  FOREIGN KEY (HouseID) REFERENCES House(HouseID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SaleID) REFERENCES Sale(SaleID),
);
```

I have a sale table

```
CREATE TABLE Sale (
  SaleID int,
  SalesManID int,
  SaleDate Date,
  SalePrice int,
  PRIMARY KEY (SaleID),
  FOREIGN KEY (SalesManID) REFERENCES SalesMan(SalesManID),
);
```

I have a table that contains both sale and customers

```
CREATE TABLE SaleToCustomers (
  SaleID int,
  CustomersID int,
  PRIMARY KEY (SaleID, CustomersID)
);
```

Comment: Why do you separate sellers and buyers at all? You can add two flags to your customer record - IsBuyer, IsSeller - but you need only one ID - CustomerID. And you FK relationships from customer to sale and house are reversed - you need relation from sale to customer (or rather two customers - seller and buyer) and from house to sale.

Comment: Your primary key does not allow one seller to sell multiple houses to the same buyer. Also, is the first name, last name, birth date, phone etc the details of the seller or the buyer? Why not have a people table, a houses table and have the connection between sellers and buyers in the sales table (or another appropriate table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entities are confused.  A customer should be a person, with information about the persion.  Then `Sales` should refer to it twice, once for buyers and o once for sellers:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
  CustomerId int PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName varchar(50),
  LastName varchar(50),
  Adress varchar(50),
  BirthDate Date,
  City varchar(50),
  HomePhone varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Sales (
  SaleID int PRIMARY KEY,
  SellerId int,
  BuyerId int,
  HouseId int,
  SaleDate Date,
  SalePrice int,
  FOREIGN KEY (SellerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId),
  FOREIGN KEY (BuyerId) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId),
  FOREIGN KEY (HouseID) REFERENCES House(HouseID)
);
```

In other words, "buyer" and "seller" are attributes of a sale, not of a person.

Comment: What if my buyer and seller can use the same identity for. eg. They can use same email id to login for buyer and seller. Now I want to add email id as the primary key since the search will be effective. What's your take on this?